# What is the meaning of " 2>>$(NULL)? " in makefile

Tags: variables, makefile

I view in ST's makefile they define coppy  command like this:
CP := cp -fp 2>>$(NULL)

What is 2>>$(NULL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of suppressing error output from the `cp` command:

- `cp -fp` Is the normal copy command, but `-f` forces the copy (existing destination files that can't be opened will be removed, and the copy will be attempted again). `-p` preserves file mode. ([cp man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html))
- `2>>` is redirecting [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29)
- `$(NULL)` I haven't seen this shortcut before, but I assume is a shortcut for a [null device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device)

Normal output ([stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)) is on file descriptor #1, so it will still be printed. Stderr ouput generated by `cp` will be sent to the null device where it is silently consumed and never displayed or written to a file.